# Show that the measures in $\mathscr E^T(X)$ constrain all the ergodic averages

Tags: ergodic-theory

I came across the following problem on *Ergodic Theory with a view towards number theory* textbook(Exercise 4.2.5.):

> Let $T: X\to X$ be a continuous map on a compact metric space. Show that the measures in $\mathscr E^T(X)$ constrain all the ergodic averages in the following sense. For $f\in C(X)$, define
>
> $$ m(f)=\inf_{u\in\mathscr E^T(X)}\left\{\int f d\mu\right\} $$
>   and
>   $$ M(f)=\sup_{u\in\mathscr E^T(X)}\left\{\int f d\mu\right\}. $$
>   Prove that
>
> $$ m(f)\le\liminf_{N\to\infty} A_N^f(x)\le\limsup_{N\to\infty} A_N^f(x)\le M(f) $$
>   for any $x\in X$.

---

We know that $ \limsup_{N\to\infty} A_N^f(x) $ converges to $\int f d\mu$ pointwise a.e. for any ergodic measure. But how to show that it is actually bounded for every point? I have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $f \in C(X)$. Fix $x \in X$. Say $\frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{n \le N_k} f(T^nx) \to \limsup_{N \to \infty} A_N^f(x)$. Let $\mu$ be a weak-$*$ limit point of the measures $\frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{n \le N_k} \delta_{T^n x}$. It's easy to see $\mu$ is $T$-invariant. Let $\lambda$, a probability measure on $\mathscr{M}^T(X)$, be the ergodic decomposition of $\mu$ (c.f. Theorem 4.8). Then, $$\limsup_{N \to \infty} A_N^f(x) = \int_X fd\mu = \int_{\mathscr{E}^T(X)} \left(\int_X fd\nu\right) d\lambda(\nu) \le \int_X f d\nu_0$$ for some $\nu_0 \in \mathscr{E}^T(X)$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you! The idea used in your answer appeared in the next section lol. And I should have thought about the ergodic decomposition theorem.

Comment: @Bach Well, I don't think it's that reverse-engineerable from the ergodic decomposition theorem. You first notice that $\limsup A_N(x) = \int_X fd\mu$ where $\mu$ is as in the answer. And then you wonder how you show the integral of $f$ w.r.t. $\mu$ is at most the integral of $f$ w.r.t. some ergodic measure. And then obviously ergodic decomposition comes to mind.